# Reloading a package from a global python script

Tags: python, python-2.6

In our codebase we have `ASCII` as default encoding and we need to change it to `UTF-8`, so in each python script we have this :

```
if not (sys.platform.startswith("win")):
    reload(sys)
    sys.setdefaultencoding('utf-8')
```

I wanted this to be in a global script so I created one and added to all python scripts

```
Globals.py
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
import os
import sys

if not (sys.platform.startswith("win")):
    reload(sys)
    sys.setdefaultencoding('utf-8')
...
```

We have set a `RIGHTIMPORT` variable in `bash_rc` which holds the parent directory of our project and all scripts can easily find the relevant files from that relative path. So to import `Globals.py` I added below code to each script:

```
import os
import sys
...

# gets the RIGHTIMPORT path and adds it to PATH variable
RIGHTIMPORT = os.popen("echo $RIGHTIMPORT").read()[:-1]
IMPORT_PATH = RIGHTIMPORT + "/import/"
sys.path.insert(0, IMPORT_PATH)

# adding global constants and configurations
from Globals import *
...
```

As `sys` package is used to insert `RIGHTIMPORT` into the `PATH` it is imported before importing all the packages from `Globals`.

My question is after executing `from Globals import *` will `sys` be reloaded or not ? I can't actually confirm it as the system is working fine and cases were it fails due to `ASCII` encoding rarely happens.

Thanks

Comment: It's not necessary to start a subprocess to gather environment variables. `os.environ` is a dict containing environment variables set.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`sys` will be reloaded. I suggest changing the condition to something that happens more often, put in `print` statement or two, and see if it reloads.

Comment: Can you provide some references which gives more info on `reload` specific to my case, I searched on net about `reload` but couldn't find anything where it was used in a different script.